# Showing that every set in a metric space is open and closed

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Define: $$d(x,y) = \frac{|x-y|}{1+|x-y|}$$

I have shown that $(\mathbb{N}, d)$ Is a metric space.

I have also been asked to describe all open balls of radii $1/3, 2/3 $ and $3$ in this metric space.

I have found that for $1/3$, $B(x,1/3) = \{x\}$,

for $2/3$, $B(x,2/3) = \{x-1,x,x+1\}$

for $3$, $B(x,3) = \mathbb{N}$. I believe all of these are correct.

For the final part I am asked to show that every set in this metric space is open and closed.

I am having trouble here. I know that I have to show that $\exists r > 0$ such that $B(x,r) \subset X$ where X is a set such that $(X,d)$ is a metric. Could someone provide a solution to this or help me find this $r$? I then have to show that the complement of $X$ is open, which I am also unsure to do.

For reference, this is a question from Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*. I cannot find any solutions to it, and have been stuck for a few days.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You already know that singletons are open balls (with radius $\frac{1}{3}$, for instance).

Comment: by singletons do you mean points? if so, how do I know that they are open balls exactly? By your hint - I am assuming I'm trying to reduce this problem so that I can use the previous work and somehow construct a union of "singleton" sets? I can't really see how to construct it - however.

Comment: @sarah_morgan1 You have showed that $B(x,\frac{1}{3})=\{ x\}$, i.e., the open ball with center $x$ and radius $\frac{1}{3}$ is the singleton $\{ x\}$. Hence the sets with only one point are open. Note that in metric space the topology is defined precisely from open balls - they form the subbasis of the topology. Since any union of open sets is open, one deduces that in the above case any set (being union of singletons which it contains) is an open set. Also the complement of any set is open because of this. Hence any set is closed as well.